Is the 2024 Ukrainian invasion of the Kursk region the first time since WW2 Russia was invaded?
It's widely claimed that the 2024 Ukrainian invasion of the Kursk region is the first time since WW2 Russia was invaded:
France24:

Ukraine's incursion, the first on Russian soil since World War II

Foreign Policy:

the first foreign invasion of Russia since World War II

NBC News:

foreign troops swept into Russia for the first time since World War II

Institute for Policy Studies:

Russia has been invaded for the first time since World War II

But are such claims true?
I ask because I thought Chinese troops invaded Russia in 1969 (albeit briefly).

My understanding is that in 1969 China only attacked Zhenbao/Damiansky island, which was contested between the two countries and not recognized Russian territory.  (They also attacked, but without success, similarly contested Tielieketi). Moreover, Chinese troops didn't occupy the island (they retreated, keeping fire control to block any russian attempt to reclaim it), so I wouldn't call it an invasion. Conversely, Kursk oblast is recognized Russian land, and Ukrainian troops have durably settled there - already for one month, and showing no intention to retreat.

You should specify what you mean by "Russia" and "Russian territory".  In WWII, relatively little of Russian territory was invaded. The German-Soviet war was mostly on Ukrainian and Belarusian territory. And the little islands which were "invaded" by Chinese were a contested territory, which China considered its own.

Stalingrad was most definitely inside the borders of the RSFSR, and I don't think Russia was any less invaded just because the land area affected was smaller than the Ukranian and Byelorussian SSRs.

Also note that cross border raids had already occurred prior to the Kursk invasion by the Freedom of Russia Legion . They probably were short enough to not count as an invasion, and they are nominally a Russian group in exile fighting against Putin. So arguably not an invasion for that reason.

Depending on your definition, Russia was invaded in 1999, during the brief period between the two Chechen Wars. At this time, due to the inconclusive first Chechen War, Chechnya was de facto independent of Russian rule. Shamil Basayev's militants crossed the border into neighboring Dagestan with the intent of annexing it and forming an Islamic union state.
While ultimately the invasion was repelled, Chechen forces held a number of border villages for 38 days.

It's a bit open to interpretation (since the territory was disputed) but Soviets argued that Chinese troops invaded Damansky Island during Sino-Soviet conflict in 1960s.
Wasn't much of an invasion, even if it technically counts
For a bonus, depending on your definition, US recon flights over USSR territory (e.g. U-2 flights) can be technically argued to be an invasion.

Soviets argued that Chinese troops invaded Damansky Island What's a source for this? (You simply linked to the same Wikipedia article that I already linked to.)

@user103496: russian sources still hold this point of view.

@user103496 - source: reading books and articles published in Russian back when I lived in USSR.
